# how to make button UIButton save when last clicked on

Tags: ios, swift, realm

basically i am trying to make a habit tracker app. i am still trying to figure out how to make cell save when it was last clicked. i am using RealmSwift

here is the function i would like to implement

```
        func setupDateAndTIme(btnCheckMark: UIButton) {

            let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince(habit.updatedAt as Date)
            let duration = Int(elapsedTime)
            let waitingTime = 45
            //change waiting time to 43200 for actual app but test w 60 smtn
            if duration < waitingTime && habit.checked == true {
                btnCheckMark.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkedOff"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                btnCheckMark.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                btnCheckMark.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "emptyCheckbox"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                btnCheckMark.isEnabled = true
            }

        }
```

as i am making this app programatically, this is the table view function

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckListIdentifier") as! CheckMarkCell

        cell.btnCheckMark.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
   @objc func checkMarkButtonClicked ( sender: UIButton) {
        print("button presed")

        if sender.isSelected {
            //uncheck the butoon
            sender.isSelected = false

        } else {
            // checkmark it
            sender.isSelected = true

        }

    }
```

here is the code for the cell

```
class CheckMarkCell: UITableViewCell {
    let habit = Habit()
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCheckMark: UIButton!

}
```

could someone tell me how to implement this function? thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to SO. A couple of things to be aware of; the question is tagged Realm but there's no realm code so it's unclear what it has to do with Realm. Also, the question is a bit unclear. You state *cell save when it was last clicked* but you cannot save a cell, a cell is a UI element. It appears there's a tableView which should be backed by a tableView dataSource. The objects within that dataSource, which is called `myArray` have data. If you want to store when the cell was clicked, update that object (a Realm object?) in the array or in the Realm database. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add weak reference to view controller into the cell
2. Call some method in view controller when the button is tapped
3. Update a flag that button is selected, e.g. `var selectedIndexes = [Int]()` where index is a row number of the cell with the button
4. Reload the cell in the table or update the button state right away.

`@objc func checkMarkButtonClicked` must be a part of the cell.

Logic: `user --tap--> cell --call_vc.updateButtonState()--> vc [saves flag] --tableView_reloadCell-->`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple cells you need a way of tracking which one was the last one, since if you scroll, cells are being reused, and you will lose that information, there are 2 easy ways of accomplish what you want

- Use the `indexPath.row` as the `tag` property of your button:
  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign the buttons `tag` property to the `indexPath.row`, then in your `checkMarkButtonClicked` you can access the `tag` property with `sender.tag`, update the flag in your array.
- Use a property in your viewModel to keep track of selections:
  Inside your `CheckMarkCell` you can have a method `configure(with viewModel: habit)`, and your `Habit` viewModel can have a property `isSelected`, then in your viewController you have an array of `Habit` objects, where you would toggle the isSelected there.